# Simple python command to capture shell execution output?

Tags: python, shell, capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running shell command from python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

When I want to capture shell execution output, I do this.

```
declare TAGNAME=`git describe --tags`
```

Simple. I looked for this in Python, but most of them looks very complex. What's the simplest way to do this? Yeah I know I can make a function, but I want to know pre-defined function if it is exist.

```
tagname = theFunc('git describe --tags')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> tagname = subprocess.check_output('git describe --tags'.split())
```

Comment: It was required to call `.strip('\n')` for returned string.

Comment: @Eonil Why call `.strip('\n')`? Does it really matter to have a `\n`?

Comment: @xiaomao Yeah. Because I will pass the string to another shell command. It's really wonderful that you can be fine with unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. You can capture the output of a command with it as well. There are many examples in the manual page how the module is used.

Example:

```
output=subprocess.Popen(["ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

The result is a tuple with stdout and stderr that was captured from the command.